# Add buttons to label name

Tags: android, kotlin

How to add Android buttons like edit or cancel to label name?

[image: enter image description]

Comment: [Adding and Handling Actions](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html)

Comment: Thanks, but how to implement menu resource to existing layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use custom tollbar instead

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

   <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and set it like this

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mTitle.setText(toolbar.getTitle());

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

it will be a simple solution for your issue.

Comment: added new answer, can you pls look at it